# How to get the pure raw HTML of a page in HTMLUnit while ignoring JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: htmlunit

I just want the text content of page and I want the fetching to be as lightweight as possible. Can I turn off all the parsing and additional loading of JavaScript, CSS and other external content that HTMLUnit does out of the box?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the closest thing to what you're looking for is:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.setAppletEnabled(false);
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

For HtmlUnit 2.13 and above, use `webclient.getOptions()`.

Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200886/extremely-simple-code-not-working-in-htmlunit-2-9-stable) and answer might be useful too. It really made things faster for me, but I had to recompile HtmlUnit...

Finally, in order to get the original content of the page (instead of the output of `asXml()`) try the following:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.yourpage.com");
String originalHtml = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be the difference between `asXML()` and `page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString()` ?

Comment: `asXML()` will format the code (for instance, add spaces whenever an html tag is opened) while `getContentAsString()` will show you the html code exactly as it is returned by the web server

Comment: Starting HTMLUnit 2.13, use webClient.getOptions() to invoke these "enable" methods.

Comment: @Mosty Is there a specific reason you are disabling applets too.