# Prevent HtmlUnit 2.13 from executing JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, html, htmlunit

Here is my code to get the page:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
```

The problem is the `webClient` always executes javascript automatically and throws me a list of error. I just want to get the raw source. How can I prevent it from executing script? I've found there is a way in version 2.9:

```
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

But `setJavaScriptEnabled()` function was deprecated. Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Please help me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Although `setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean)` was deprecated it was added to the `WebClientOptions` member of the `WebClient`. Here is the [doc](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean)).

In order to disable JavaScript you should do this:

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Additionally, if you you want to get the raw HTML code from the webpage you should take a look at this question:

[How to get the pure raw HTML of a page in HTMLUnit while ignoring JavaScript and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091359)

Take into account that even the `asXml()` method change the formatting as well as the content of the web page you fetch (even if JavaScript is disabled).

Comment: Thank you! It really saves my day! But when I try to display the source as a part of my page in a `<div>`, the browser will be "Not responding" for some source page. Do you have any idea why?