# HtmlUnit Timeout Debugging

Tags: logging, timeout, htmlunit, apache-httpclient-4.x, freeze

I am using HtmlUnit to login to websites. Despite setting a connection timeout and Javascript timeout the script just hangs while attempting to log in to a site. This site is an internal page not open to the web.

Following is the webClient configuration that i am using:

```
      RefreshHandler rh = new RefreshHandler() 
      {
            public void handleRefresh( final Page page, final URL url, final int seconds ) 
            {

            }
      };

    webClient.setRefreshHandler(rh);

    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(90000);  //Set Connection Timeout to 1.5 minute 
    webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(45000);     //Set JavaScript Timeout to 0.75 minute

    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);

     System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,SSLv2Hello");
```

**NOTE:** I am using IBM *Jdk 1.7* and *HtmlUnit 2.12* (the latest one). I have included all the 21 dependency jars in the buildpath of my project. It does not use any logging mechanism. It prints out everything on the console using println statements.

I am trying to figure out the following:

**Why is it that the script hangs and does not timeout ?** I have researched this issue in this forum. I know people have run into it but have not come accorss any concrete solution for it. There is nothing on sourceforge that indicates an "open" bug in HtmlUnit either.

**Is there way to ensure the script never hangs?** I thought setting the two timeouts above would have done the trick. **What might be the other reasons that would make a script wait forever other than network/connection issues and unresponsive javascript?**

I am aware that HtmlUnit uses Apache HttpClient to make the http calls.I want to debug this issue without building from source (I want to keep it as my last option as i am fairly new to java). **Is there a way to run Htmlunit/HttpClient in the debug/verbose mode so that it prints out everything onto the console. Does the HtmUnit API support this?**

I used all the 3 given below but none of it seemed to work:

```
System.getProperties().put("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog", "debug");  

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.All);

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(Level.All);
```

First one was specified in the "logging" section on the HtmlUnit homepage.

I appreciate your assistance/comments. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't quite know what the following line does, I will answer as it wasn't there:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,SSLv2Hello");
```

You should first try to simplify your code as much as you can to get the minimal case (eg: you haven't clarified if your application hangs with javascript disabled.

Once you've done that you should take a close look at the HtmlPage you're fetching. Check what other object the page is fetching, particularly iframes. Then take a look at this question and the answer:

[Extremely simple code not working in HtmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200886/extremely-simple-code-not-working-in-htmlunit-2-9-stable)

(Yes, that was me experiencing the same symptoms as you). However, I went a bit farther and used jstack to get a lower lever idea of the threads and what they were doing. In short (and as a spoiler), there was some kind of issue regarding an iframe load loop. The solution... well... you're not going to like it. Check the question and you'll find out :)

As a side note, try to a enable all logging, set the `throwException*` flags to `true`, remove any specific logging command (if you are setting `.setLevel(Level.All)` and you are not getting anything something must be wrong... but as HtmlUnit provide quite a lot of logging by default you might not need to add more).

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.setJavaScriptTimeout(1000);
```

The HtmlUnit uses `driver.setJavaScriptTimeout(1000)` to set JavaScript time out.