# HTMLUNIT v. 2.15 Bug Thread deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, htmlunit

I'm using **htmlunit (version 2.15)**; I noticed a memory leak issue with the WebClient class: all webClient instances are not cleaned by garbage collector.

The issue seems caused by threads deadlock:

```
JavaScriptExecutor.run(JavaScriptExecutor.java:182)
```

I tried to call **webclient.closeAllWindows** for each instance but doesn't work.
I'm sure that **ALL** references to webClient objects are deallocated.

How can i properly **clean** the memory from webClient objects to avoid OOM? Garbage collector can't delete webClient objects due to thread lock.
I googled for hours but I don't find any working solution.
Thanks.

Comment: This looks a bit different than the issue I faced a while ago but maybe could shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200886

Comment: I looked at this page [http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1259/](http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1259/). Seems they found a solution in a previous version, but still doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the same bug with 2.15 and created a reproducible test case that shows the issue to the developers.  Hopefully they will address it quickly.  You can see the bug and my test case here...

http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1638/

Comment: Just a note the developers addressed the issue and I tested out there fix with from SVN SNAPSHOT and it fixes the issue.

Comment: As a final followup HTMLUnit 2.16 with this bug fix is officially release on April, 20, 2015